# Is there a way of starting a pyaudio stream from a separate process when using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pyaudio

I'm trying to creating an interactive real-time audio application where the user should be able to control a few key audio processing parameters through a GUI. At present I'm using pyaudio for real-time processing and streaming of the audio data and matplotlib widgets to create the GUI. The code responsible for running the GUI and streaming are each on a different python process through the use of the multiprocessing package.

Is there a way to trigger the start of the pyaudio stream but from the GUI running on the other process. Below is how I imagine the code might look, but it obviously doesn't work. The difficulty I'm having is how to stop and trigger the pyaudio instance from across the other child process.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value
import pyaudio
import wave

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def GUI():
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(10, 10)

    ax1: plt.Axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

    def play_click(event):
        stream.start()

    def pause(event):
        stream.stop()

    def onchange(value):
        gain.value = value

    slideraxis = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.02])
    slider = Slider(slideraxis, label='gain', valmin=0, valmax=1.0, valinit=gain.value, valstep=0.01)
    slider.on_changed(onchange)

    pause_btnaxis = fig.add_axes([0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
    pause_btn = Button(pause_btnaxis, 'Pause audio')
    pause_btn.on_clicked(pause)

    play_btnaxis = fig.add_axes([0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
    play_btn = Button(play_btnaxis, 'Play audio')
    play_btn.on_clicked(play_click)

    plt.show()

def stream_audio(process_state: Value, gain: Value, pause: Value):
    # open file for streaming
    input = r'path/to/audio'

    wf = wave.open(input, 'rb')

    chunk = 1024

    # create Pyaudio instance
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    # call back function which executes processing the stream processing
    def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
        # extract the parameter values
        gain_val = gain.value

        if wf:
            wf_rate = wf.getframerate()
            audio = wf.readframes(chunk)
            audio = np.frombuffer(audio, dtype=np.int16).astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 2)
        else:
            audio = np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.int16).astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 2)

        audio_data = audio * gain_val

        return audio_data.astype(np.int16).tobytes(), pyaudio.paContinue

    # open a .Stream object to write the wave file to
    # output = True indicates the sound will be played rather than recorded

    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate=wf.getframerate(), stream_callback=callback, start=False, output=True)

    stream.start_stream()
    while stream.is_active() and process_state.value:
        time.sleep(5)

def main():

    process_state = Value('b')
    process_state.value = True

    gain_value = Value('f')
    gain_value.value = 1.0

    processes = [
        Process(target=ui,
                args=(process_state,
                      gain_value,
                      pause)),

        Process(target=stream_audio, 
                args=(process_state,
                      gain_value, pause))
               ]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```